# ERROR ITMS-90283: Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle is invalid [Missing code-signing certificate]

Tags: macos, electron, code-signing, electron-builder

**Version**:

- **electron: 5.0.1**
- **electron-builder: 21.2.0**
- **electron-notarize: 0.1.1**
- **electron-webpack: 2.7.4**
- **Working on: MacOS Catalina 10.15**

The `dmg` file is working perfectly.  But when I try to verify via Transporter, I am getting the following error.

**Error**

[image: error]

**Build Configuration**

```
"build": {
    "appId": "<APP_ID>",
    "productName": "<PRODUCT_NAME",
    "copyright": "<COMPANY_NAME>",
    "afterSign": "scripts/notarize.js",
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources",
      "output": "release"
    },
    "mac": {
      "hardenedRuntime": true,
      "gatekeeperAssess": false,
      "category": "public.app-category.developer-tools",
      "target": ["mas"],
      "icon": "resources/icon.icns",
      "identity": "<IDENTITY>",
      "provisioningProfile": "build/mac.provisionprofile",
      "type": "distribution",
      "electronLanguages": ["en"],
      "entitlements": "build/mac.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "build/mac.plist"
    },
    "mas": {
      "hardenedRuntime": false,
      "provisioningProfile": "build/mas.provisionprofile",
      "type": "distribution",
      "electronLanguages": ["en"],
      "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mas.plist",
      "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mas.inherit.plist"
    },
    "dmg": {
      "sign": false,
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 220
        },
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 220,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "files": [
      "dist/",
      "node_modules/",
      "app_prod.html",
      "main.prod.js",
      "main.prod.js.map",
      "package.json",
      "assets/"
    ],
    "win": {
      "target": ["nsis"]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": ["deb", "AppImage"],
      "category": "Development"
    }
},
```

**notarize.js**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const { notarize } = require('electron-notarize');

exports.default = async function notarizing(context) {
  const { electronPlatformName, appOutDir } = context;
  if (electronPlatformName !== 'darwin') {
    return;
  }

  const appName = context.packager.appInfo.productFilename;

  return await notarize({
    appBundleId: process.env.BUNDLE_ID,
    appPath: `${appOutDir}/${appName}.app`,
    appleId: process.env.APPLE_ID,
    appleIdPassword: process.env.APPLE_ID_PASS,
  });
};
```

**mac.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

**entitlements.mas.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.application-identifier</key>
    <string>APPLICATION_ID</string>
    <key>com.apple.developer.team-identifier</key>
    <string>TEAM_ID</string>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
      <string>BUNDLE_ID</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>

    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
    <true/>

    <key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write</key>
    <true/>

    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>

    <key>com.apple.security.files.all</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <string>security</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

**entitlements.mas.inherit.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.inherit</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

**My certficates**

[image: certficates]

**Build folder**

[image: Provision]

**Provision Profiles**

[image: Provision]

Also, the [Notarization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_your_app_before_distribution) step is also passed. Is am missing anything here?

Comment: What is "Transporter"?

Comment: @NoGrabbing The Transporter app is a macOS tool that helps to upload your binary to App Store Connect.

Comment: @NoGrabbing Do you have any idea about this issue?

Comment: I don't, sorry. Perhaps ask at the Apple Developer forums and/or check the `electron-builder` github issues list. I had a hellish time with OSX code-signing but I wasn't trying to do a MAS build.

Comment: Did you ever figure this issue out?

Comment: @hisnameisjimmy I gave up on this. The issue is with the electron. So we yank app from AppStore and give the option to download .dmg file from the website.

Comment: @MuhsinKeloth Damn, brutal

Comment: Have you found any solution on this error?

Comment: @SagarSukode No

Answer (score 2):

I had the [same error message with a newer version of electron](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/5092#issuecomment-704123531). What actually was the issue for me, was that I had multiple `x.provisionprofile`s, and instead of `embedded.provisionprofile` (as is stated by the electron builder documentation) one of the others was used thus leading to this error. You can check the complete source code and build setup here:
https://github.com/johannesjo/super-productivity

Comment: omg, that was so painful to figure out. It's a silence bug

Answer (score 0):

@hugo der hungrige - thanks for the tip... for others experiencing same issue... according to many instructions out there, you have these 2:

- embedded.provisionprofile
- embedded.mas.provisionprofile

... set your config so **both the "mac" and "mas" use the same embedded.mas.provisionprofile**.

```
{
    "productName": "alooper",
    "appId": "com.gieson.alooper",
    "directories": {
        "buildResources": "buildResources",
        "output": "release"
    },
    "afterSign": "./buildResources/notarize.js",
    "mac": {
        "hardenedRuntime": false,
        "gatekeeperAssess": false,
        "type": "development",
        "target": [
            "mas"
        ],
        "artifactName": "${productName}-${version}-${os}.${ext}",
        "category": "public.app-category.music",
        "provisioningProfile": "./embedded.mas.provisionprofile",
        "entitlements": "./entitlements.plist",
        "icon": "./app/assets/icon/alooper.icns"
    },
    "mas": {
        "hardenedRuntime": true,
        "type": "distribution",
        "target": [
            "pkg"
        ],
        "artifactName": "${productName}-${version}-${os}.${ext}",
        "category": "public.app-category.music",
        "provisioningProfile": "./embedded.mas.provisionprofile",
        "entitlements": "./entitlements.mas.plist",
        "entitlementsInherit": "./entitlements.mas.inherit.plist",
        "icon": "./app/assets/icon/alooper.icns"
    }
}
```